# Is it wrong to specify action in URL to simplify partial updates?

Tags: rest, url, put

Is it totally incorrect to specify action in the URL to simplify partial update. I am designing URL for appointment resource. Most frequent update of an appointment is to update its status. For example appointment can have any of the following status:

Scheduled
Arrived
Cancelled
Done

Now for updating the status, I am looking at following options:

a> PUT /api/appointments/{id}

With appointment details (and new state going through the message body.

b> PUT /api/appointments/{id}/{new-state}

Nothing goes through the message body. The URL is used to indicate the new state of the specified appointment.

c> PUT /api/appointments/{id}?state={new-state}

Nothing goes through the message body.

The advantage of b & c is they are very light and have minimum data going over the n/w.

Will I be going totally against the REST philosophy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Options B and C would go against some of the more pure REST beliefs. REST philosophy would argue in the favor of always updating the entire resource with PUT.

A better way would be to use the PATCH method with the partial data in the payload. See  [Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/performance#patch) for an example.

`PATCH /api/appointments/{id}
   {"state":"new-state"}`

But, I would advise against worrying too much about going against REST philosophy due to the fragmented conventions and practices that exist in the community. A RESTful approach is fine. It is more important that your API be consistent, easy to consume and friendly to developers.

Comment: Thanks. I also find PATCH approach elegant. I am using ASP.Net Web API to implement my REST services. While ASP.Net Web API does supports use of PATCH verb, the recommended way to apply patch is to use OData extension. We are not using OData right now. Is there a way to create a delta object as indicated in Partial Updates in http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2012/08/15/odata-support-in-asp-net-web-api.asp without using OData?

Comment: You have a lot of options. You could pass a Dict<string,obj> of changes. That could emulate the delta class.

Comment: Thanks @kampsj. I decided to create a **DeltaPatcher** of my own. [Here](https://github.com/viklele/DeltaPatcher) is the link for anyone to use it. It is only minimally tested. It works similar to OData Delta.